# c++ stl priority_queue with a custom comparator as function parameter

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

I want to use priority_queue and pass it to a function:

```
// compare points according their distance to some target point
struct MyComparator {
    Point target;
    MyComparator(Point t) : target(t) {}

    bool operator() (const Point& p1, const Point& p2) {
         return distance(target, p1) < distance(target, p2);
    }
};

typedef priority_queue<Point, vector<Point>, MyComparator> myque;
void myfunc(const Point& target, myque& que) { ... }

// call myfunc
Point target = ...;
myque queue(MyComparator(target));
myfunc(target, queue); 
// error :
no matching function for call to ‘myfunc(const Point&, myque (&)(MyComparator))’
```

How can I resolve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: `myque queue(MyComparator(target));` is a function declaration. You can add another set of parentheses and it'll work: `myque queue((Mycomparator(target)));` The term to search for is *most vexing parse*.

Comment: Thanks, it works! Another evidence about the complexity of C++...

Comment: curious about what does `myque queue(MyComparator(target));` means? What operation is this line willing to achieve?

Comment: It declares a priority_queue with a customized comparator. The comparator depends on the value of the passed object "target". In my case, It tries to compare elements in the queue by their Euclidean distance to "target" point.